# NSString with emoticons/emojis url encode

Tags: ios, objective-c, encoding, nsstring, urlencode

I am trying to take the contents of a UITextField that may contain special characters and emojis and turn it into something I can pass in a GET request to a PHP service.

If I do not encode the string at all, the emojis show up just fine (I can see them in the DB and they come back to me properly)... but if I add special chars (~!@#$%, etc.) the GET request chokes.

So I run the string through the url encoder:

```
[commentText stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding];
```

I am using the NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding to get the emojis out properly, which works, but using this to encode returns a nil string.  In fact, the only encoding that does not return a nil is UTF8, but that munges up the emoji unicode with percent-escapes.

How do I do this?  Do I have to write my own string replacement for this case, or is there an iOS way to do it that I am not seeing?

Cheers,

Chris

Comment: `NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding` clearly _doesn't_ work if it's returning nil. As for `NSUTF8StringEncoding`, "_... that munges up the emoji unicode with percent-escapes._" That's exactly what percent escaping does. What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: I need something that will keep the full unicode bit intact while escaping the things that will prevent the GET request from going through.  UTF8 takes and escapes chars in the emoji's unicode which renders it unusable.  For these three emojis () UTF8 encoding turns them into (%F0%9F%98%84%F0%9F%98%98%F0%9F%98%B3).

Comment: Encoding with NonLossyASCII keeps them intact.

Comment: Except it's not keeping them intact as passing `NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding` to `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:` returns nil, as you said. That's because the string is not ASCII.

Comment: Ok... so what is the solution?  The only way to get the emojis to transfer successfully through the middleware to the DB is to not encode them at all.  But that only works if the passed string does not contain any special chars.  It seems that with iOS 7 adopting the Unicode 6 spec for emoticons, there is no framework function to handle both extended-chars and url encoding.  I am basically asking if there actually is one, and I just have not found it, or if I need to roll my own (which I ended up doing just so I could move on).

Comment: Unescape the escaped string server-side before passing it further upstream.

Comment: @neilco thanks!  Turns out the creation of a NSURL from my string fails, because of the implicit UTF8 encoding...  Will give your idea a go and see if it gets me across the finish line.  Would you mind posting it as an answer, so I can accept it (assuming it works).

Comment: Can i change decode emoji in ios which is encoded in php side ? if yes than how can i do this in both side. i try but no working only both encode and decode same size . Otherwise not working :( so please give me some solution . Thanks in Advanced.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding` to `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:` returns `nil` because the string you're passing in is not ASCII. Using `NSUTF8StringEncoding` percent escapes the emoji characters and that's the result I would expect. If your server-side middleware is not automatically unescaping the emoji from the query string, then you should look to do that in your server-side code if it's causing issues upstream.

Comment: That was the ticket.  Encoding via UTF8 on the way out works, providing the middleware unescapes prior to stuffing into the DB.  However, the curious thing is unless I decode the resultant JSON using NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding, I get garbage.  NonLossy gives me the actual emojis.  Not sure why, but that worked for me.

Answer (score 6):

Use this to escape emoji:

```
NSString *escapedEmoji = [NSString stringWithCString:[emojiString cStringUsingEncoding:NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

And this to unescape emoji:

```
NSString *unescapedEmoji = [NSString stringWithCString:[escapedString cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] encoding:NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding];
```

Comment: Your example code works perfect. I had to encode chat message to send as ASCII string.

Comment: i'm using this encoding in a chat application. Im my case this works fine for (iOS to iOS messages) but it add some extra unicode characters from (iOS to android). What should i do i this case.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the below code to encode emoji string

```
NSString *uniText = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[youremojistring UTF8String]];
NSData *msgData = [uniText dataUsingEncoding:NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding];
NSString *goodMsg = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:msgData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```