# UILabel not showing emoji

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, emoji

I'm facing a problem about displaying emoji in a UILabel.
I get this data from a web service (i cannot change the way i get the data) : 
This value is from the debugger :

```
__NSCFString *  @"emoji \\ud83d\\ude1b\\ud83d\\ude1d"   0x000000017405ea80
```

Value from NSLog :

```
emoji \ud83d\ude1b\ud83d\ude1d
```

if i assign this value to my UILabel text property i get on the screen :

```
emoji \ud83d\ude1b\ud83d\ude1d
```

I tried to encode and decode the string using :

```
NSData *data = [string dataUsingEncoding:NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding];
NSString *dataValue = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
return dataValue;
```

and when i try :

```
NSData *data = [string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *output = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding];
```

i get the emoji on the screen but if a string does not have emoji inside it will be nil and get empty label on device.

I can't get it to work correctly.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your code, the second one.. and it is working perfectly:

Here is what i have:

[image]

and the output:

[image]

removing the emoji string `\\ud83d\\ude1b\\ud83d\\ude1d` just leave `emoji`. 
this is using simulator, i wonder the error only appear on the device? while in simulator it's working?

Comment: Thanks man but why when there is no emoji the string is nil ?

Comment: @MikeMorris, it is not nil to me.. i dont know what's causing that in your case, trying look at this [discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19304535/nsstring-with-emoticons-emojis-url-encode) might be related to your problem.. but i dont think your string is non ascii.. hmm.. i do believe that your problem is different..

Answer (score 0):

Try to set your `UILabel` with:

```
//Example
[NSString stringWithUTF8String:"\ud83d"]
```

Comment: Nope thank for your support. I close the question i store the string value and then if the emoji string i use the stored value.