# Showing Emoji with string in textfield in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am new to swift development. I need to show the emoji inside the text field and labels.
I also need to send them to server because Application is multi-platform.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23670959/how-to-show-emoji-in-uilabel-ios and

Comment: `textField.text = ""` – where is the problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UILabel not showing emoji](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31059988/uilabel-not-showing-emoji)

Answer (score 10):

On Xcode version 7.2.1+, you can use the below shortcut to show the symbols panels and insert the emoji:

Shortcut: (press the below three keys together)

**<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>**

Answer (score 9):

You can declare a string variable with text and an emoji inside using its unicode number (1F603 is unicode number for an open faced smiley), like so:

```
let str : String = "Smiley \u{1F603}"
```

Then with your UITextField/UILabel, set the .text attribute to be the string.

```
yourTextField.text = str
//or for a UILabel.
yourLabel.text = str
```

Comment: Is this unicode iOS only or can be used on all platforms

Comment: Unicode Defination - an international encoding standard for use with different languages and scripts, by which each letter, digit, or symbol is assigned a unique numeric value that applies across different platforms and programs.     

So yeah, It will be consistent on other platforms.

Comment: @shivamkaushik Please give me any source of Unicode to clear out the topic

Comment: Here is an extensive list of Emoji codes. Use the five characters after the U+

http://www.unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html

Answer (score 5):

```
textField.text=@"";
```

for above Emoji --- put the focus at place of emoji in `UITextField` and go to

**Edit > Emoji & Symbols in Xcode 7.3** 
and select what ever emoji you want.

**OR**

**Set Unicode values directly in code:**

```
var string: String = "I want to visit मुंबई. "
var character: Character = ""
```

**Use hexadecimal to set values**

```
var string: String = "\u{61}\u{5927}\u{1F34E}\u{3C0}"

var character: Character = "\u{65}\u{301}"
```