# How can I "puny" encode emoji?

Tags: ios, character-encoding, emoji

Emojis have [percent encoded representations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19304535/nsstring-with-emoticons-emojis-url-encode), but they also have ["puny" representations](https://www.punycoder.com/). How does this work? Is there an easy way to convert emojis to punty codes?

For example, the key emoji () can be represented by the percent encoding `%f0%9f%94%91` and  the puny code `xn--kv8h`.

Answer (score 1):

There are actually many built solutions for iOS including this pod: [Puntycode-Cocoa](https://github.com/Wevah/Punycode-Cocoa).

The general method for encoding Unicode as ASCII using punycode is explained in detail on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punycode).